# PHP's unlink() method not working on Centos 7

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos7, file-permissions

I have a website powered by php on centos 7 and this website has methods for upload and delete file in the centos' "/var/www/html/uploadfile" directory. PHP's "move_uploaded_file" method and "unlink" method was not working before but I connecting centos with ssh and i write in terminal:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/uploadfile

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/uploadfile

chmod a+rwxt /tmp /var/www/html/uploadfile
```

and "move_uploaded_file" method is working succesful now. But "unlink" method still not working.

I will say one more thing, "uploadfile" folder's owner is root, but uploaded file's owner is apache. Could it be because of this situation?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBkES.png)

(This methods was working succesfully in my localhost. I think my problem is about centos's file-permissions.)

Comment: Your problem is indeed with file perms. Make sure the folder and files are owned by the user with which the PHP process is running.

Comment: Folder is owned by root and files are owned by apache and i don't know what to do.

Comment: If the PHP process's USER is different from the file you want to `unlink`, then the deletion will generally fail. the USER with which PHP is running needs to have `+w` permissions to the files you want to delete.. The usual assumption is that the same PHP process created those files in the first place.. but in your case this might be different.

Comment: Also I've no idea why you set the `+t` sticky bit to your files/folders... this additionally complicates things...

Comment: Sorry my friend. I am fine for software but i am still a newbie for linux commands. Actualy i found this linux terminal commands in internet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fine, my code:

```
<?php include "dbbaglanti.php" ?>
<?php

    $silinecekice=$_POST['silinecekice'];
    $sorgu2=mysqli_query($baglan, "SELECT kurs_id, ice_link, kursici_index  FROM icerik WHERE ice_index=$silinecekice");
    $sorgu2info=mysqli_fetch_array($sorgu2);
    $kursid=$sorgu2info['kurs_id'];
    $icelink=$sorgu2info['ice_link'];
    $kursiciindex=$sorgu2info['kursici_index'];

    unlink("$icelink"); //unlink(uploadfile/xxx.mp4);

    $biticesil=mysqli_query($baglan, "DELETE FROM bitirilenicerik WHERE ice_id='$silinecekice'");
    $sorgu=mysqli_query($baglan,"DELETE FROM icerik WHERE ice_index='$silinecekice'");
    header("location: kursuyonet.php");
    mysqli_close($baglan);
?>
```

And I say it again; I'm sure the problem isn't in my code. Because this code working succesfully in my localhost. I think this problem is indeed with file perms.

Answer (score -1):

put your code to check it

without your code nobody can solve your problem

Comment: As this is not an answer, please move it to the comments section

Comment: add comment on op post need 50 repus and i have 34 only. @Ron

Comment: That cannot be an excuse to put comments as answers..

Comment: i wanna solve the users problems and when i can't comment on op posts so how should i fix them problems ? if you can send my comment in op post so do it and iff not, please stay to op back and i check can solve him problem or not. and if not, i will delete my post

Comment: In fact, the php file that contains the method may confuse someone who is not familiar with the working logic of my website, but simply the logic of the method working with own parameter inside is: _italic_ **bold** `<?php unlink(uploadfile/xxx.mp4); ?>`

Comment: put your code to see someone could to solve your problem or not ! without your code no one (repeat: no one) can help you